# android app: is it possible to copy a list view from one fragment and display it in another?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I am trying to create an app where I have an edittext that can save into a listview. I have that listview invisible because I want to display the list in another fragment. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have your EditText in Fragment A save to a model.  In Fragment B you can display your ListView based on the data in the model.

Comment: How would I go about saving the EditText to a model and then displaying it in the other fragment?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.  If you're trying to save text from an EditText, then just save the string to SQLite or SharedPreferences, and use that data to build a ListView.

Comment: I'm saving it to SharedPreferences in the fragment with the EditTexts. I'm not sure how to build the ListView in another fragment with that, however.